# Error using PasswordDeriveBytes.CryptDeriveKey

Tags: .net, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm currently porting an ASP.NET app (.NET 4.8) to ASP.NET Core MVC (3.1)

```
    internal static ICryptoTransform CreateEncryptor(string Password)
    {
        var des = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
        var pdb = new PasswordDeriveBytes(Password, new byte[0]);
        des.Key = pdb.CryptDeriveKey("RC2", "MD5", 128, new byte[8]);
        des.IV = new byte[8];
        return des.CreateEncryptor();
    }
```

this code is used to encrypt something on the url but when used on .net  core mvc its returns an error
[image]

> PlatformNotSupportedException:'CryptDeriveKey' requires Windows Cryptiographic API

does anyone know a fix?

Comment: Have you switched operating systems? The environment you're running on doesn't seem to be supported, you can take a look at this:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/security/cross-platform-cryptography

Comment: no. but when I run the old app on the same OS (Win 10) it works, but running it (Win10) with .net core 3.1 it throws the error.